# Open crontab file with php

Tags: php, cron, file-get-contents

I have the following php code to try to get the contents of my root's crontab, but nothing is returned.

```
$cronFile = '/var/spool/cron/root';

$current = file_get_contents($cronFile);
echo $current;
```

the permissions on the cron file look like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- root root
```

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the file contains anything?

Comment: Yes, it has text for a couple cron jobs I created

Comment: Since you have only one echo, it could very much be that there is an error, but due to php settings not getting displayed. Enable displaying errors, set error reporting to E_ALL and use `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

Comment: var_dump gives me bool(false). setting with error_reporting(E_ALL);  does not give me any errors

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is executed withing the `open_basedir` (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restrictions you are not allowed to open files outside the specified vhosts, e.g. `/var/spool/cron/root`.

Of cource you can include the folder `/var/spool/cron` in the `open_basedir` setting but I highly do not recommend this as this setting is a security measurement.

Comment: That requires it to be set, on a new installation it's not set. Also it would throw an error if `open_basedir` restriction would be in effect.

Comment: On my phpinfo() page it shows "no value" under open_basedir.